# VB - Baseball Teams - Percentage of games won

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code so far:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnBaseball_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBaseball.Click
    Dim baseball() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("baseball.csv")
    Dim query = From line In baseball
        Let data = line.Split(","c)
        Let city = data(0)
        Let won = CInt(data(1))
        Let lost = CInt(data(2))
        Let pct = CDbl(data(3))
        Select city, won, lost
    dgvBaseball.DataSource = query.ToList
    dgvBaseball.CurrentCell = Nothing
    dgvBaseball.Columns("city").HeaderText = "CITY"
    dgvBaseball.Columns("won").HeaderText = "WON"
    dgvBaseball.Columns("lost").HeaderText = "LOST"

End Sub
```

End Class

***  Here is the text file:

```
Baltimore,93,69
Boston,93,69
New York,95,67
Tampa Bay,90,72
Toronto,73,89
```

How do I revise my code so that when it reads the file, it has to calculate the 
percentage of games won and the output is this:

```
TeamWon Lost    Pct
New York    95   67 0.586
Boston          93   69 0.574
Tampa Bay   90   72 0.556
Toronto         73   89 0.451
Boston          69   93 0.426
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in c#.
Had to lookup how do you calculate those percentages (I'm from Europe :))

```
string[] baseball = new string[] {"Baltimore,95,67",
    "Boston,93,69",
    "New York,95,67",
    "Tampa Bay,90,72",
    "Toronto,73,89"};

    var query = from line in baseball
        let data = line.Split(',')
        let city = data[0]
        let won = Convert.ToInt32(data[1])
        let lost = Convert.ToInt32(data[2])
        let pct = won / (decimal)(won + lost)
        select new { city, won, lost, pct};
```

Comment: Hi Peri,  That works, I did not know it was that simple.  I too, had to look how to get the percentage (not a baseball fan).  Anyways I appreciate your help.  Fred

Comment: Upvoting and accepting as an answer is the way to thank here ;)